# Subversion svn update - Not working

Tags: perl, svn, bash

I'm trying to setup subversion, so everytime someone commits a change, it updates a working directory that we'll use on a dev box as the 'test' site.

I've setup post-commit, and added the line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/svn update /home/administrator/sites/checkmyid --username root --password xxx
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work when run automatically, but when I run it at the command prompt:

> sudo ./post-commit
>   /home/administrator/sites/svn

It works fine?

I've tried chaning the owner of the working directory to www-data but it doesn't seem to want to work?

FIXED IT MYSELF

Basically, it was a permissions problem. I used the command

sudo chown -R www-data /home/administrator/sites/checkmyid

And now it works perfectly!

Comment: What is this? Why is there a space after the #! at the start of your script? Why does it specify perl as an executor when the code is obviously bash code? What does "want to work" mean? Please post your actual code, and the actual symptoms.

Comment: That is actually my code.

It's a file 'post-commit' that i've written.

It works when I run the file from the command line using sudo, but not when svn executes it.

Answer (score 2):

Your post-commit script contains bash code, but the shebang is saying to use Perl to run it.

Plus, shebang lines should be on their own line; put the actual commands to run on another line.

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R www-data /home/administrator/sites/checkmyid